# Change the border Color of reactstrap input component

Tags: css, reactjs, reactstrap

I am trying to override the color of reactstrap input component
Currently It looks like this
[image]

and this is my implementation:

```
          <Input
                    invalid={formik.errors.password ? true : false}
                    className="login-input"
                    id="password"
                    name="password"
                    placeholder="Password"
                    type="password"
                    autoComplete="new-password"
                    onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
                    onChange={formik.handleChange}
                    value={formik.values.password}
                  />
```

css:

```
.login-input:focus {
    border-color: white !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reactstrap inputs also get a `box-shadow`, so try this:
(`!important` might not be necessary)

```css
.login-input:focus {
    border-color: white !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
```